# Is it possible to fix width of the row title column?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to fix the width of the row title column? On scrolling, when passing rows 999 to 1000 or 9999 to 10000, the row titles' width changes. If there is controls fixed on first row, it causes an annoying blinking effect. Hiding titles does not fix the problem; in spite of titles are not seen, effect occurs.

Comment: The maximum number of rows in xl2007 and higher is 1,048,576. If you want to stop the *'annoying blinking effect'* then the 'row title column' for row 1 will have to be the same width as row 1,048,576. Do you **really** want row 1 to look like `[            1]` ?

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks. You may be right on that side; but the issue you have mentioned is something different. But I ask whether it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way to do that is by turning off the display of headings entirely (View tab of the ribbon).

Comment: "Turning off the display of headings entirely" does nothing on the effect I've mentioned. As I've said, altough the titles are not seen, the effect still remains.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps we are not discussing the same thing. If I keep on headings (View tab, Show group, Headings checkbox checked) and scroll down to row 900 something, scrolling down until row 1000 comes into view indeed makes the columns shift to the right a little bit. But as soon as I turn headings off, this behaviour stops and the columns stay where they are. What Excel version are you on?

Comment: An excel 97-2003 workbook; but I open it in 2007. I have a worksheet which has a lot of controls on its first fixed row. This effect is seen on it. But if I put just one control on a worksheet which titles turned off to see what happens; it is not seen. I think if there are few controls; the effect is fast as not to be seen. Weird.

Comment: Actually I want row headings; but, with fixed width enough not to shift other columns right when passing from 999 to 1000 and from 9999 to 10000 by scrolling

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is a combination you cannot achieve with Excel. Period.